# 'module' object has no attribute 'RawConfigParser' in coverage.py

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I was able to successful install coverage using -user and try to use api as we have wrapper which was difficult to call  coverage from command line So I call api and write import coverage But I endup with following error.Could you please provide the input.

when I write simple import it works but it failes if I call from wrapper.
In short, we have one script in which call functional script or main script.

Is it possible to do coverage of inner module also if we invoke other module also

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coverage-3.6.1a1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/coverage/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from coverage.control import coverage, process_startup
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coverage-3.6.1a1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/coverage/control.py", line 9, in <module>
    from coverage.config import CoverageConfig
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coverage-3.6.1a1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/coverage/config.py", line 13, in <module>
    class HandyConfigParser(configparser.RawConfigParser):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RawConfigParser'
```

Comment: Can you show the code your are using? Currently we do not have enough information to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was, we have same file which customize version which does not contain  RawConfigParse.So I have download configparser and install it. it works fine for me.Really it is nice tool